# C# Writing the response of a REST call to a Text File

Tags: c#, rest, encoding, text-files, messagebox

I'm having a difficult time writing the contents of my request from my rest call to a txt file.

I get a response and I can output it to the console, but I really would like to write it to a text file. I'm leaning towards it being an encoding issue but I'm just not sure where to set that or configure that.

The contents of the Messagebox and file that I write are empty.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create the web request  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ecn") as HttpWebRequest;

            // Set type to POST  
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            string query = "?s=PVSW";

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            data.Append("&query=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query));

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data = " + data.ToString());

            // Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            // Set the content length in the request headers  
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            // Write data  
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                // Console application output  
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());


                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:/Response.txt");

                // write a line of text to the file
                tw.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

                // close the stream
                tw.Close();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to write to the C: drive on the server or on your local machine..?

Comment: Correct, this is a pure test only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `reader.ReadToEnd()` to write to the console and then you call `reader.ReadToEnd()` again for the MessageBox and the file output.  You need to collect the data from `reader.ReadToEnd()` into a temp var (`char[]` or whatever), then feed that to all three outputs.